# Question on Gemara Keritot

Tags: masechet-kereitot

In Keritot 2b, the Gemara has a back and forth as follows:

Rabbi Yochanan: if you violate all 34 keritot in one lapse of awareness you need a chatat for every single one, and we learn this from the fact that karet by a sister is specified

Rav Bivi: how can you learn from a sister to all other cases

Rabbi Yochanan: don’t you hold by the principle that if something is specified outside of the Klal it comes to teach something, just like how eating a Shelamim while Tamei is separated from the general prohibition of eating korbanot while tamei to teach that only things similar to a Shelamim (that go on the altar) are chayav karet and this excludes an animal consecrated for temple handiwork

Rav Bivi: of course I believe in the principle, and it should be like this- just like a sister which is a permanent issur needs to bring a chatat, so too all other permanent issurim need to bring chatat, and this excludes and Eshet Ish which could be permitted with divorce. Therefore, yes for every karet prohibition you need to bring a separate chatat, except for Eshet Ish.

Now the Gemara answers no, since the general pasuk forbidding Arayot already grouped the sister with the rest of the prohibitions, that’s how we can make the connection between the two.

So now to my question, wouldn’t this answer of the Gemara ruin the idea before with the Shelamim? Now according to this Svara of the fact that they’re grouped together being proof to the similar law, so too by the Shelamim case since all forbidden Kodashim are grouped in one pasuk, then presumably even the קדשי בדק הבית would be an issur of karet like the rest (even though it doesn’t go on the altar).

I thought this was such an obvious question. Anyone have any insight?

Comment: The passuk by erva is a hekesh (because it says “ha’eileh”) whereas by kodesh it just says a general word of kodshim which doesn’t infer the power of a hekesh but just a klal.